# Did Troy quit the Air Conditioning Repair School?

Tags: plot-explanation, community

Did Troy quit the AC Repair school at the ending of Season 3, or did he continue?

It is unclear, as in Season 4 it is never mentioned.

Also, at the end of Season 3, Troy only states that he ordered the AC repair school to behave like a normal school.

Answer (score 4):

Since he was their *chosen one*, they would follow his orders.  So he ordered them to act like a normal school, and then he quit.  This why in season 4 it hasn't been mentioned, as now the AC Repair School isn't pestering him anymore to join them.  They're now normal, so they're not going to chase after Troy, since they don't believe in weird stuff like *chosen ones*.

Answer (score 0):

As you said yourself, it was never explicitly mentioned if he was still in the Air Conditioning Repair School or not.

Seeing that he has left the show by now, this secret probably will never be solved completely.

However, there are some strong indicators that he left the AC school at the end of Season 3:

- Apparently he was already finished with the two year program after his short time there. [In S04E13 he says](http://www.tvfanatic.com/quotes/i-passed-all-the-classes-so-now-i-just-do-yoga-while-the-teache/):

> **Troy:** I passed all the classes, so now I just do yoga while the teachers write down my wisdoms.

- He took part in a "normal" Greendale College class in Season 4, titled *"Nicolas Cage: Good or Bad?"* So it appears that he is back in the usual Greendale course program.
- After Pearce's death, he embarks in a trip around the world to get the inheritance. So if he had not left the school before that point, he definitly did then.